# BASH: How to find all files in a remote directory that are >7 days old and use RSYNC to copy them to a local directory?

Tags: bash, find, rsync

I am very new the scripting and am working on a problem.

Is it possible to:

1) find all files in a remote directory (on a remote server) that are less than 7 days old

and then...

2) use rsync to copy those files to a local directory

I have been trying to figure this out for about 12 hours but nothing queit like this problem comes up. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1. yes it possible, search for `[bash] ssh find old file` . But warning, search the "whole remote machine" may take a lot longer than you expect or may get you in trouble with you IT org. Best to limit your search to dirs that you are responsible for , maybe `/run/usr/data` and below (or something like that). 2. my `rsync` days are behind me. yes, its possible, but you'll probably find that `rsync` has cmd-line options that will find those files for you. (hmm, running on the remote machine, with your local machine as the target). Good luck.

Comment: Run `find` on the remote computer to create a temporary file (say `tmpfile`) containing all the files less than 7 days old. Then on the remote use `rsync` with the `--files-from` and `--no-R` (no relative) options to transfer from the remote to local. E.g. on the remote `rsync  -uai --no-R --files-from="tmpfile" / localbox:/path/to/save/to` See [rsync(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html) for the option details, especially the use of `--no-R` and the *srcdir* of `'/'` which will ensure the filenames in `tmpfile` are taken from the filesystem.

Comment: Note: you can also pull the files from the remote to the local using `tmpfile` on the remote. See the `--files-from` section that says: In addition, the `--files-from` file can be read from the remote host instead of the local host if you specify a "`host:`" in front of the file (the host must match one end of the transfer) As a short-cut, you can specify just a prefix of `":"` to mean *"use the remote end of the transfer"*. (see the example given in the man-page)

Comment: Lastly note, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). This question is a *"How do I use `rsync` question."* This does not mean your question isn't a valid question (it's actually quite good), it just means you have posted it to the wrong site....